# Why was this game drawn on Lichess?

Tags: draw, lichess

https://lichess.org/qgvWa0ly

I (Black) was losing and ready to resign soon. As far as I can tell, there should be no stalemate or 50 move rule applicable. I had offered a draw earlier, but it was declined. Can the opponent accept the draw later after first declining? That wouldn't be fair.

```
[FEN ""]
[Event "Rated Rapid game"]
[Site "https://lichess.org/qgvWa0ly"]
[Date "2018.08.25"]
[White "Tigerov"]
[Black "JordanRieger"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]
[UTCDate "2018.08.25"]
[UTCTime "00:43:31"]
[WhiteElo "2216"]
[BlackElo "1969"]
[WhiteRatingDiff "-14"]
[BlackRatingDiff "+6"]
[Variant "Standard"]
[TimeControl "600+0"]
[ECO "C47"]
[Opening "Four Knights Game: Scotch Variation Accepted"]
[Termination "Normal"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Nc3 Nc6 4. d4 exd4 5. Nxd4 Nxd4 6. Qxd4 d6 7. Bg5 Be7 8. O-O-O O-O 9. e5 dxe5 10. Qxe5 Bd7 11. Bd3 Re8 12. Rhe1 Bd6 13. Qd4 h6 14. Bh4 Be7 15. Ne4 Nxe4 16. Qxe4 Bg5+ 17. Bxg5 Rxe4 18. Bxd8 Rxe1 19. Rxe1 Rxd8 20. Bc4 Re8 21. Rxe8+ Bxe8 22. Kd2 Bc6 23. g3 Kf8 24. Ke3 Ke7 25. Kd4 b6 26. b4 f6 27. h4 b5 28. Bb3 Kd6 29. c3 a6 30. f4 Bf3 31. c4 Be2 32. c5+ Kd7 33. Bd5 c6 34. Be4 Bc4 35. a3 Be2 36. Bg2 Bc4 37. Bf3 Be6 38. Bd1 Bc4 39. g4 Be6 40. g5 fxg5 41. fxg5 hxg5 42. hxg5 Bf5 43. Ke5 g6 44. Bb3 Ke7 45. Bd1 Bh3 46. Bf3 Bd7 47. Be4 Kf7 48. Kd6 Be8 49. Bxc6 Kf8 50. Bxe8 Kxe8 51. c6 Kd8 52. Kd5 Kc8 53. Kd6 Kd8 54. Kc5 Kc7 55. Kd5 Kc8 56. Kd6 Kd8 1/2-1/2
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In a chess there's a 3-fold repetition rule, if the same position appears 3 times, a player can call a draw. Your opponent allowed a 3-fold repetition, hence, the game was drawn.

```
3k4/8/p1PK2p1/1p4P1/1P6/P7/8/8 w - - 11 57
```

**Edit: clarifying in light of comments:**

Note that the draw does not happen until claimed by a player, and since you didn't claim it, your opponent must have. Why would they claim a draw in a winning position where they had more time on their clock? On lichess.org, you can control the "claim draw on threefold repetition automatically" setting. Yours is set to "when time remaining <30 seconds", but the opponent's must have been set to "Always". Players who normally play under faster time controls sometimes use the "Always" setting to ensure predictable draws under time pressure. You got lucky in this situation because your opponent didn't recognize the 3-fold repetition, and their winning chances were undone by their settings.

Comment: Ah, of course. Sorry, I have no idea why I didn't realize that. I'm well aware of the 3-fold repetition rule, I just spaced out there. But that leads to another question: why was the draw automatic? In my lichess settings, I have the option "claim draw on threefold repetition automatically" set to "when time remaining <30 seconds". My time was at 0:43.

Comment: Or maybe the opponent had the setting at "Always". That must be it.